# Unit Testing Django Views that uploads image to s3

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, django-views, django-rest-framework

I wrote a simple unit test to test django view. The view uploads the image file that is passed along with the request object to S3.

Code:

```
        url = 'view-endpoint-url'
        myfile = open('pathtoimage')
        payload = {'data1': 'xyz', 'file': myfile}
        response = client.post(url, payload, MULTIPART_CONTENT)
```

At this point when the view under test is called: the image file is stored as expected in request.FILE['file'] of type InMemoryUploadedFile.

When the view tries to open(request.FILE['file']) and read() I get a

```
 IOError no such file or directory
```

I'm confused because the image file does exist within the location but for some reason it's not being picked up. I did the similar testing using curl command and all works fine.

Is there any workaround that can help me with the unit testing?

Update:

Basically I'm trying to grab the file path of the InMemoryUploadedFile to unit test the view

**Solution**

Fixed this issue by reading the file in the same view under test rather than using another utility method to read the InMemoryUploadedFile.

For some reason the InMemoryUploadedFile is loosing track of the file path when it's read using a utility method in a different folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this issue by reading the file in the same view under test rather than using another utility method to read the InMemoryUploadedFile.

For some reason the InMemoryUploadedFile is loosing track of the file path when it's read using a utility method in a different folder.